# Find if an array has duplicates in O(N) time, with auxiliary structure

Tags: c, arrays, time, duplicates

I want to know if it's possible to find if an array has duplicates in O(N) time in C, but you can use an auxiliary data structure, like a hash table. Remember that the insertion in the data structure counts as well for the time. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: What have you tried? You mentioned hash table - and it looks like a good direction - what would you do with it?

Comment: This problem is not specific to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a hash table may work.

For every word you calculate the hash and try to insert it in the table bucket. If the bucket is non-empty, you compare the words in the bucket and if the new word does not exist you add it to the bucket, othrwise you found a duplicate.

This means you process the words of the input only once, however, you may need to check the words in the buckets multiple times.

Processing the input is O(N), processing the buckets is a function of the hash table size.

A table of size 1 will result in checking every word N times, so would be O(N<sup>2</sup>). A table size of N will result in checking every word 0 times and so would be O(N).

Comment: "*you compare the words [the hash?] in the bucket and if the new word does not exist*" what about collisions?

Comment: @alk, You make a hash of an input word. The hash is a number between 0 and the has table size-1. In the hash table entry for that hash (called a bucket) there can be multiple words (the collisions). You compare each word in the hash bucket with the input word. If the word does not exist in the bucket, add it (a new collision), else the word is a duplicate.